# git clone failed to begin relaying via HTTP

Tags: linux, github, ssh

When Using git clone, I come into an error.
Here is the command and the error information.

```
[user@linux]$ git clone git@github.com:username/repertory.git
FATAL: failed to begin relaying via HTTP.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Except for git@github, git clone https://...... and git clone git://...... works well. So i guess there is something wrong with ssh protocal, then i checked ssh.

```
[user@linux]$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

It seems that I can connect to github through ssh protocol properly. But what's wrong with git clone through ssh?

Comment: It seems you are using proxy configuration in your `.gitconfig`. Please post the relevant configuration (you may omit any passwords).

Answer (score 1):

This error message comes from [`connect.c` from SSH](http://failed%20to%20begin%20relaying%20via%20HTTP)

It is a [SSH Proxy Command -- `connect.c`](https://github.com/larryhou/connect-proxy), the simple relaying command to make network connection via SOCKS and https proxy: You can make SSH session beyond the firewall with this command.

So check if such a connection is needed: it could very well be needed if you are in an enterprise, behind firewall, but in that case do contact your  IT support team to check the validity/approval of such a solution.

And that error message indicates that even this SSH mode (relay through https proxy) might be blocked.

If you are not in an enterprise setting, and don't need proxy, do remove them (`HTTPS(S)/PROXY`) from your environment variables and your `git config` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Proxy, many corporate firewalls block access to the `CONNECT` method on ports other than 443. GitHub operates an SSH server listening on port 443, using the host "ssh.github.com".

First, configure your SSH `~/.ssh/config` with the following:

```
Host github.com, ssh.github.com
    User git
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
    ProxyCommand socat - PROXY:localhost:%h:%p,proxyport=3128
```

in the example above I'm assuming you're running a web proxy on host `localhost` and port `3128` (e.g. [`cntlm`](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)).

You may also substitute [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) with [`nc`](https://nmap.org/ncat/) or [`connect-proxy`](https://github.com/larryhou/connect-proxy) with slightly different syntax.

Test with:

```
ssh -T git@ssh.github.com
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

then with:

```
git clone git@ssh.github.com:username/repository.git
```